# Build Failed on Wasm project on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: .net, uno-platform

I am new to Uno and I am trying to generate a Wasm application from Ubuntu20.04.
I am testing it with the first Tutorial described at "https://platform.uno/docs/articles/getting-started-tutorial-1.html".

I created a uno project using the command : 
`$ dotnet new unoapp -o Tutorial1`

I went to the specific folder using :
 `$ cd Tutorial1/Tutorial1.Wasm/`

I tried :
 `$ donet run`
 as well as :
`$ donet build /bl`

 **I got 1 Error**:

```
/home/jmarc/.nuget/packages/uno.wasm.bootstrap/1.3.4/build/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.targets(126,2): error : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory [/home/jmarc/GitRepos/dodeka/Tutorial1/Tutorial1.Wasm/Tutorial1.Wasm.csproj]<br>
/home/jmarc/.nuget/packages/uno.wasm.bootstrap/1.3.4/build/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.targets(126,2): error :    at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec) [/home/jmarc/GitRepos/dodeka/Tutorial1/Tutorial1.Wasm/Tutorial1.Wasm.csproj]<br>
/home/jmarc/.nuget/packages/uno.wasm.bootstrap/1.3.4/build/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.targets(126,2): error :    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [/home/jmarc/GitRepos/dodeka/Tutorial1/Tutorial1.Wasm/Tutorial1.Wasm.csproj]<br>
/home/jmarc/.nuget/packages/uno.wasm.bootstrap/1.3.4/build/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.targets(126,2): error :    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() [/home/jmarc/GitRepos/dodeka/Tutorial1/Tutorial1.Wasm/Tutorial1.Wasm.csproj]<br>
/home/jmarc/.nuget/packages/uno.wasm.bootstrap/1.3.4/build/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.targets(126,2): error :    at Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.ShellTask_v2ed6794b633a8ebf33d51d6d21f9d6a587ebe09e.RunProcess(String executable, String parameters, String workingDirectory) in D:\a\1\s\src\Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap\ShellTask.cs:line 470 [/home/jmarc/GitRepos/dodeka/Tutorial1/Tutorial1.Wasm/Tutorial1.Wasm.csproj]<br>
/home/jmarc/.nuget/packages/uno.wasm.bootstrap/1.3.4/build/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.targets(126,2): error :    at Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.ShellTask_v2ed6794b633a8ebf33d51d6d21f9d6a587ebe09e.RunPackager() in D:\a\1\s\src\Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap\ShellTask.cs:line 579 [/home/jmarc/GitRepos/dodeka/Tutorial1/Tutorial1.Wasm/Tutorial1.Wasm.csproj]<br>
/home/jmarc/.nuget/packages/uno.wasm.bootstrap/1.3.4/build/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.targets(126,2): error :    at Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.ShellTask_v2ed6794b633a8ebf33d51d6d21f9d6a587ebe09e.Execute() in D:\a\1\s\src\Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap\ShellTask.cs:line 182 [/home/jmarc/GitRepos/dodeka/Tutorial1/Tutorial1.Wasm/Tutorial1.Wasm.csproj]
```

I checked that the file */home/jmarc/.nuget/packages/uno.wasm.bootstrap/1.3.4/build/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.targets* exists and it does.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
By the way. installed .Net Sdks are :

```
$ dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.405 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.102 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the 3.1.405 sdk. Because they have the same install path(/usr/share/dotnet/sdk), there might be conflicts when you run dotnet, the OS either doesn't know which to pick, or it picks the wrong one, possibly corrupting the working dirrectory as well, hell knows.
alternatively, run ldconfig as root, maybe some shared libraries got out of sink between the two sdks? This is what I did when encountering a similar error.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but it did not work. 
Additionally, the Uno website requests that .Net 3.1 to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install mono, right?
https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/1947#issuecomment-625468775

I tried:

- Add the Mono repository to your system
- Install Mono

Then run the following commands:

- `dotnet new -i Uno.ProjectTemplates.Dotnet`
- `dotnet new unoapp -o MyApp -ios=false -android=false -macos=false`
- `cd MyApp/MyApp.Wasm`
- `dotnet build`